# On Docker for Windows, how do you push to a registry being port forwarded to localhost on the host machine?

Tags: docker, ssh, portforwarding, docker-registry

I'm just going to put this here, because it was very difficult to find information on this topic and I ended up solving it myself.

**Setup**

- Bastion host in aws with a public ip address
- Registry (image registry:2) on a private subnet behind bastion host
- Successful ssh port forwarding through bastion, connecting localhost:5000 to registry:5000

`curl localhost:5000/v2/_catalog` provides a list of installed registries.

So far so good.

```
docker tag {my image} localhost:5000/{my image}
docker push localhost:5000/{my image}
```

**Result**

```
The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/{my image}]                                                 
Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused
```

How do we connect to a registry port forwarded to localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some obscure posts suggesting that you need to make a custom privileged container and do your ssh bastion port forwarding inside the container. This is essentially working around a problem introduced by the fact that the docker daemon is actually running inside a virtual machine!

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/

You can find a hint here:

> I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST The host
>   has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access).
>   From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS
>   name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal IP address
>   used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in
>   a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows.

So given the above, I reasoned that even though this advice is for containers, the docker daemon itself is probably acting on docker cli commands from within a similar context.

Therefore, first you need to add host.docker.internal:5000 as an insecure registry in your docker daemon setup. On Docker for Windows, this can be found in Settings > Daemon > Insecure registries. Unfortunately this doesn't count as localhost, so this has to be done (Docker allows localhost insecure registries by default). Then simply:

```
docker tag {my image} host.docker.internal:5000/{my image}
docker push host.docker.internal:5000/{my image}
```

Success!

Hopefully this helps some other very confused developers.